# How does this array of pointers print this unexpected result?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

While trying to understand Array of pointer in C language, I wrote this simple program. But I don't understand how this works properly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int array [] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,5}, *ip = array+4;
    printf("%d\n", ip[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
6
```

Can someone explain how the output of this Array of pointer comes out to be 6?

Comment: What would you expect it to print?

Comment: `* ip = arr+4` sets the pointer to point to the 4th element of `arr` (the `5`). So `ip[1]` is the 5th element of the original `arr` (the `6`).

Answer (score 3):

It may help if you understand what array index notation means.  When you see `x[y]` it is *exactly* equivalent to `*(x + y)`.

So taking `ip[1]`, this is the same as:

```
*(ip + 1)
```

Since `ip` was assigned the value `arr + 4`, this is the same as:

```
*(arr + 4 + 1)
```

Which is:

```
*(arr + 5)
```

Which is:

```
arr[5]
```

Which contains the value 6.

Answer (score 1):

Here `arr` points to that starting  of  `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,5}` ie toward `1`.

Then `arr+4` will point to element `5` *(4 int positions away from 1)*.

so `ip` will point array `{5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,5}`

then , `ip[0]` will be `5` , `ip[1]` will be `6` .... etc.

```
ip[1] == arr[4+1] == arr[5] == value 6
```

So the result is not unexpected.... It is as EXPECTED !

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 1):

According to **C in Depth by S.K. Srivastava**

> The name of an array is a constant pointer that points to the first
> element of the array i.e., it stores the address of the first element,
> also known as the base address of the array.

Hence when you use the name of an array it will act as if you are using `&arr[0]`, and when you add `4` to it it gives you the address of `arr[4]` which is `5`. Therefore, the pointer `ip` now contains the address of element containing `5`.
Now, in the next line when you write `ip[1]` it's nothing but `*(ip+1)` i.e., you add `1` to `ip` and then dereference that pointer. When you added `1` to `ip` it started pointing to the next element i.e., `ip` contains the address of element `6` and Hence `6` is printed. 
**See also:**
[https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ab/15-123S09/lectures/Lecture%2005%20-%20%20Arrays%20and%20Pointers.pdf](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eab/15-123S09/lectures/Lecture%2005%20-%20%20Arrays%20and%20Pointers.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

*ip = arr+4 *//This means ip will point to the value 4 positions from the base of the array arr.*

So ip is {5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,5}

Hence ip[1] = 6 is the correct output.